# Android SortedList java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Asked to get item at 0 but size is 0

Tags: android, sortedlist

```
public Order gimmeThePendingOrderToDeliver(String _id, String my_phone) {
        for (int i = 0; i < orderSortedList.size(); i++) {
            Order o = orderSortedList.get(i);

            boolean a = o.isCanceled_by_user(), b = o.isCanceled_by_owner(), c = o.isDelivered();
            String d = o.getDelivery_guy();
            if (_id.equals(o.get_id()) && !a && !b && !c && d.equals(my_phone)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "IM HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return o;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(context, orderSortedList.get(0).get_id(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
```

cant iterate Android SortedList returns error as descriped in the title ,, any help will be appreciated . THANKS in advance.

Comment: your issue isn't actually related to an index, your issue is related to debugging. something like this should be quite simple to solve with breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

When `orderSortedList` is empty, it doesn't enter the `for` loop, and thus, it immediately reaches the bottommost `Toast` statement where `orderSortedList.get(0)` produces an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since the list is empty.